# Spring Cloud Config @Value throwing No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [java.lang.String]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I have successfully established connection with spring cloud config service to read my props in `application.yml`file externally in a config repo. But, when it tries to read the values I get this error

Exception:

`Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [java.lang.String]`

My Config class & value I'm trying to read:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${qws.client-realm}")
    protected String clientRealm;
```

Application.yml which is external:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

qws:
  client-role: qws-client
  client-user-name: svc-client
  client-realm: QWS_CLIENT_REALM
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: https://config-service.abcd.com
      fail-fast:  false
      username: abcd
      password: xyz
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
```

Spring Boot is Parent & cloud dependencies and versions. No build issues.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

LOGS when my client application starts & tries to read config through config-service (externally). Config service talks to config repo which has `application.yml` file externally. Look at FIRST 3 LINES of the Below logs

```
2020-04-20 22:14:25.999 [,,] INFO  [main                               ] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator                                - Fetching config from server at : https://config-service.abcd.com
2020-04-20 22:14:27.423 [,,] INFO  [main                               ] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator                                - Located environment: name=my-service, profiles=[dev], label=null, version=bfb7e95bb2840bd2e6ede62, state=null 
2020-04-20 22:14:27.423 [,,] INFO  [main                               ] o.s.c.b.c.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration                              - Located property source: CompositePropertySource {name='configService', propertySources=[MapPropertySource {name='configClient'}, MapPropertySource {name='overrides'}, MapPropertySource {name='https://gitrepo.com:config.git/repo/my-service/dev/application.yml'}]}
```

Full Exception Which is occurred after above logs connection from config-service:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [java.lang.String]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.my.service.Application.main(Application.java:29)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.LinkedHashMap<?, ?>] to type [java.lang.String]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.convertValueIfNecessary(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:263)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:91)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:539)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer$1.getProperty(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:133)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getPropertyAsRawString(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:74)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:145)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:851)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49670', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: I'd try not using versions from like 2 yrs ago for starters :). You aren't going to find support / docs / code for versions that old. Regardless, it tells you what the issue is. Your property type is a String and its expecting a HashMap.

Comment: Thanks @SledgeHammer I have updated the version tried multiple 2.1.3, 2.1.5 and 2.1.6 as well. didn't yet work

Comment: Also you aren't using it correctly. Config Service serves property sources from /{application}/{profile}/{label}.

Comment: @SantoshRaviteja can you wrap the url inside double quotes here: `uri: "https://config-service.abcd.com"`

Comment: Added the uri in qotations and also changed versions no luck

Comment: /{application}/{profile}/{label} for security purpose I have given dummy value above. However it is correct from my end

Comment: @SantoshRaviteja Check this out. this might help
https://github.com/srempfer/spring-cloud-config-sample/blob/master/README.md